# How to setup the date of an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, setup

On a new iPhone (not connected to the phone network),
running iOS 7,
date is actually set to January the 1st, 1970.

It is easy to change the date by scrolling the day.

How is it possible to enter the date and time directly,

to avoid scrolling through each day from 1970 to 2014?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't find any relevant answer before asking this question. I searched for "date iPhone" which seems large enough and correctly targeted. No one facing this problem will search for "year" or "iOS 7" but experts who already know the problem is created by iOS 7.

What's the best way to improve either the original question or this unavoidable duplicate?

Comment: Now that we have two questions with different wording for the same issue which are linked together, it will be much easier for people searching with either term to find the same answers.